# How do I make an object move or gravitate to a another object in p5.js?(whilst its moving)

Tags: p5.js

I'm currently making a zombie game, and I've been trying to figure how to get the zombie to move towards the player. I'm also trying to make a shooting system, if you have any tips on that let me know. Thank you! :)
Heres the code:

```
let round;
let zombie, player
let x, y;
let health, speed, damage, playerhealth;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
round=1;
  zombie = {

    x: 200,
    y: 200,
    //increase by 100 each round until round 9
    health: 150,
    speed: 5,
    damage: 20
  };
  player = {
    x: 200,
    y: 200,

    //default
    health: 100
  };
}


function draw() {
  background(220);
  //player
  fill('green');
  ellipse(player.x, player.y, 20, 20);
  //HUD or something
  fill('black');
  text(''+player.health, 10, 10)
  //zombie(s)
  fill('gray');
  rect(zombie.x, zombie.y - 200, 20, 20);
  if (dist(player.x, player.y, zombie.x, zombie.y) <= 100) {
background(0);
textSize(20);
text('You died \n Round '+round,165,200)

  }
  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    player.y = player.y - 2;
  }
  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    player.y = player.y + 2;
  }
  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    player.x = player.x - 2;
  }
  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    player.x = player.x + 2;
  }

}
```

Comment: You might want to read and watch the associated videos from Chapter 5 of The Nature of Code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_xJMH8VvAE&list=PLRqwX-V7Uu6ZV4yEcW3uDwOgGXKUUsPOM&index=37

Comment: unrelated, but you may want `keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)` rather than `keyIsPressed && keyCode === UP_ARROW`

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you use [vectors](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Vector) to deal with positions and velocities. I you don't already know it, some basic linear algebra will go a long way in games programming.

Here is a version of your code with a moving zombie:

```
let round;
let zombie, player;
let x, y;
let health, speed, damage, playerhealth;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  round = 1;
  zombie = {
    pos: createVector(500, 200),
    //increase by 100 each round until round 9
    health: 150,
    speed: 1,
    damage: 20,
  };
  player = {
    pos: createVector(200, 200),

    //default
    health: 100,
  };
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  //player
  fill("green");
  ellipse(player.pos.x, player.pos.y, 20, 20);
  //HUD or something
  fill("black");
  text("" + player.health, 10, 10);
  //zombie(s)
  fill("gray");
  rect(zombie.pos.x, zombie.pos.y, 20, 20);
  if (p5.Vector.sub(player.pos, zombie.pos).mag() <= 30) {
    background(0);
    textSize(20);
    text("You died \n Round " + round, 165, 200);
  }
  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    player.pos.y -= 2;
  }
  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    player.pos.y += 2;
  }
  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    player.pos.x -= 2;
  }
  if (keyIsPressed && keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    player.pos.x += 2;
  }
  zombie.pos.add(p5.Vector.sub(player.pos, zombie.pos).limit(zombie.speed))
}
```

Rather than store a `x` and `y` coordinates, it stores `pos` vector for the player and zombie. `p5.Vector.sub(player.pos, zombie.pos).mag()` is the distance between the player and zombie. `p5.Vector.sub(player.pos, zombie.pos)` is the vector from the zombie to the player, and `.mag()` is the magnitude of that vector, i.e. its length.

The line that makes the zombie move is:

```
zombie.pos.add(p5.Vector.sub(player.pos, zombie.pos).limit(zombie.speed))
```

Or in pseudo-code:

```
zombie_pos = zombie_pos + (player_pos - zombie_pos).limit(zombie_speed)
```

If the `.limit(...)` wasn't there, this would be:

```
zombie_pos = zombie_pos + (player_pos - zombie_pos)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
zombie_pos = zombie_pos - zombie_pos + player_pos
```

Which is equivalent to

```
zombie_pos = player_pos
```

This would make the zombie move to the player in one frame. By adding the `.limit(zombie.speed)`, you can limit the zombie movement speed, so that they move towards the player (in the direction of `p5.Vector.sub(player.pos, zombie.pos)`, the vector from the zombie to the player), but only move by `zombie.speed` pixels every frame.