# How do I make a object move towards the mouse in p5.js?

Tags: p5.js

I'm making a zombie game in p5js, does anyone have any recommendations on to make a shape or object move towards the mouse(this will be used to make the gun)? and if anyone knows how to make more enemies spawn more often each round that would be nice to!:)
Sorry if the solution is super simple, I still kinda new!

code:

```
let dogmode;
let round;
let zombie, player;
let x, y;
let health, speed, damage, playerhealth;
function setup() {
  dogmode=false;
  createCanvas(400,400);
  
  
  round = 1;
  bullet ={
    damage:20
  };
  //Player and zombie parameters
  zombie = {
    pos: createVector(500, 200),
    //increase by 100 each round until round 9
    health: 150,
    speed: 1,
  
  };
  player = {
    pos: createVector(200, 200),

    //default
    health: 100,
  };
fill(0);

   
}

  
function draw() {
  if( dogmode===true){
    player.health=player.health+100;
    
  }
  background(220);

  stroke(0);
  
  line(player.pos.x,player.pos.y,mouseX,mouseY);
  fill('gray')
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,10,10);  
  push();
  //player
  fill("green");
  ellipse(player.pos.x, player.pos.y, 20, 20);
  //HUD or something
  fill("black");
  text("" + player.health, 10, 10);
  //zombie(s)
  fill("gray");
  rect(zombie.pos.x, zombie.pos.y, 20, 20);
  //Damage system
  if (p5.Vector.sub(player.pos, zombie.pos).mag() <= 30) {

    player.health = player.health - 1;

  }
  
  //Health detection
  if (player.health <= 0) {
    background(0);
    textSize(20);
    text("You died \n Round " + round, 165, 200);
  }
  
  if (keyIsDown(87)) {
    player.pos.y -= 2;

  }
  if (keyIsDown(83)) {
    player.pos.y += 2;

  }
  if (keyIsDown(65)) {

    player.pos.x -= 2;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(68)) {

    player.pos.x += 2;
  }

  zombie.pos.add(p5.Vector.sub(player.pos, zombie.pos).limit(zombie.speed))
  pop();
//Create bullet
  if(mouseIsPressed ){
  fill('yellow')
  ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,5,5);
  //Shoots bullet
}
  
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make an object move or gravitate to a another object in p5.js?(whilst its moving)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253660/how-do-i-make-an-object-move-or-gravitate-to-a-another-object-in-p5-jswhilst-i)

Comment: The answer to this question is practically identical to the answer to your previous question! It's just now the vector representing the direction of movement needs to be calculated once at the time the bullet is fired and the direction is the difference between the mouse position and the player position (instead of player position minus zombie position).

Comment: I don't really understand... So if I declare 

Mouse={};

Answer (score 1):

In order to fire a bullet you need to:

1. Determine the direction of motion at the time the bullet is fired.
2. Save that vector so that the direction remains constant for the life of the bullet.
3. Update the position of the bullet each frame after it is fired.

Determining the direction of motion is simple vector arithmetic if you have two vectors, `A` and `B`, and subtract `A - B` you will get a vector representing the offset from `B` to `A` (i.e. pointing in the direction of `A` from `B`):

[image: Vector arithmetic diagram]

It is important to save this direction vector, because as the player, mouse, and bullet move the result of this computation will continually change; and bullets don't usually change direction once fired.

```js
const BULLET_SPEED = 5;

let player;
let bullet;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  bullet = {
    damage: 20,
  };
  player = {
    pos: createVector(width / 2, height / 2),

    //default
    health: 100,
  };
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  stroke(0);

  // By taking the difference between the vector pointing to the mouse and the
  // vector pointing to the player we get a vector from the player to the mouse.
  let mouseDir = createVector(mouseX, mouseY).sub(player.pos);
  // Limit the length to display an indicator of the bullet direction
  mouseDir.setMag(30);
  // Because we want to draw a line to the point mouseDir offset away from
  // player, we'll need to add mouseDir and player pos. Do so using the static
  // function so that we don't modify either one.
  let dirOffset = p5.Vector.add(player.pos, mouseDir);
  
  // direction indicator
  line(player.pos.x, player.pos.y, dirOffset.x, dirOffset.y);
  fill("gray");
  ellipse(dirOffset.x, dirOffset.y, 10, 10);
  
  //player
  fill("green");
  ellipse(player.pos.x, player.pos.y, 20, 20);

  if (keyIsDown(87)) {
    player.pos.y -= 2;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(83)) {
    player.pos.y += 2;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(65)) {
    player.pos.x -= 2;
  }
  if (keyIsDown(68)) {
    player.pos.x += 2;
  }

  //Create bullet
  if (mouseIsPressed) {
    // Notice there can be only one bullet on the screen at a time, but there's
    // no reason you couldn't create multiple bullets and add them to an array.
    // However, if you did, you might want to create bullets in a mouseClicked()
    // function instead of in draw() lets you create too many bullets at a time.
    bullet.firing = true;
    // Save the direction of the mouse;
    bullet.dir = mouseDir;
    // Adjust the bullet speed
    bullet.dir.setMag(BULLET_SPEED);
    // Position the bullet  at/near the player
    bullet.initialPos = dirOffset;
    // Make a copy so that initialPos stays fixed when pos gets updated
    bullet.pos = bullet.initialPos.copy();
    //Shoots bullet
  }
  
  if (bullet.firing) {
    fill('yellow');
    ellipse(bullet.pos.x, bullet.pos.y, 5, 5);
    
    // move the bullet
    bullet.pos.add(bullet.dir);
    
    if (bullet.pos.dist(bullet.initialPos) > 500) {
      bullet.firing = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
```